# How to achieve a search for a certain year & amount using C#

Tags: c#, sql

Here is a small demo of a SQL database, where one can add, update delete members from a SQL server.

There are two tables in a single SQL Server DB, one is “members” second is “overview”.

- In members there is distinct ID column and members personal info like name, address telephone etc.
- In overview there are only three columns which are dID, year & amount.

There is one single windows form, language is c# and project is built in Visual Studio 2010, and of course data base in SQL Server 2010.

The windows form has  a “reset, insert, update & delete”  buttons.

- There is one more button besides the dID text box where a distinct ID can be inserted and after clicking Search button the last entry made about the member shows by filling all the text boxes where name address telephone appear. This serves the function that member full info can be seen and changes can be made or can be removed from dB.
- There are two text boxes in particular, which are Year & Amount, which shows that the member has paid a certain amount for the certain year.

But as I mentioned in the text boxes you can only see the last entry made. What function I want to achieve is that after inserting dID of person x  I could only in the year text box able to insert lets say any previous year and the press search which should like normally fill all the text boxes with info, and in the amount text box should show me the entry from the dB that according to the year I entered how much amount is there or there is nothing which means that may be member has not paid for a certain year.

I need help in achieving this logic programmatically therefore I would like to request assistance.

The present program is as follows :

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text; 
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SQLDatabase 
{
     public partial class SQLDBDisplay : Form
     {
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=JG-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated Security=True");

     public SQLDBDisplay()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
     SqlDataAdapter da;
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();


     private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         SqlDataReader reader;
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
         try
         {
             string sql = "SELECT * FROM members where dID =  '" + txtdID.Text + "' ";
             txtYear.Text = sql;
             cmd.Connection = con;
             cmd.CommandText = sql;
             con.Open();
             reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 txtID.Text = reader["ID"].ToString();
                 txtName.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
                 txtAddress.Text = reader["Address"].ToString();
                 txtMobile.Text = reader["Mobile"].ToString();
                 txtEmail.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
                 txtdID.Text = reader["dID"].ToString();

             }
             con.Close();

             sql = "SELECT * FROM Overview where dID =  '" + txtdID.Text + "' ";
             txtYear.Text = txtYear.Text + " : " + sql;
             cmd.Connection = con;
             cmd.CommandText = sql;
             con.Open();
             reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 txtYear.Text = reader["Year"].ToString();
                 txtAmount.Text = reader["Amount"].ToString();
                 txtdID.Text = reader["dID"].ToString();

             }
             con.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
         }
     }

     private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         txtdID.Text = ""; txtName.Text = ""; txtAddress.Text = "";
         txtMobile.Text = ""; txtEmail.Text = ""; txtYear.Text = "";
         txtAmount.Text = "";
     }

     private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
         string Sql = "INSERT INTO members (dID, Name, Address, Email, Mobile) VALUES ( '" + txtdID.Text+ "','" + txtName.Text + "','"
+ txtAddress.Text + "', '" + txtEmail.Text + "', '" + txtMobile.Text + "')";
         cmd.CommandText = Sql;
         cmd.Connection = con;
         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
         Sql = "INSERT INTO Overview (dID, Year, Amount) VALUES ('"+ txtdID.Text +"' ,'" + txtYear.Text + "','" + txtAmount.Text +
"')";
         cmd.CommandText = Sql;
         cmd.Connection = con;
         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
         MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted Scuessfully!!!");
         for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
         {
             if (this.Controls[i] is TextBox)
             {
                 this.Controls[i].Text = "";
             }
         }
     }

     private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          try
         {
             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
             string Sql = "Update members set Name = '" + txtName.Text + "', Address = '" + txtAddress.Text + "', Email = '" +
txtEmail.Text + "', Mobile = '" + txtMobile.Text + "'  WHERE dID = '"
+ txtdID.Text + "'";
             cmd.CommandText = Sql;
             cmd.Connection = con;
             con.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             con.Close();

             Sql = "Update overview set Year = '" + txtYear.Text + "', Amount = '" + txtAmount.Text + "' WHERE dID = '"+ txtdID.Text+"'";
             cmd.CommandText = Sql;
             cmd.Connection = con;
             con.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             MessageBox.Show("Data Scuessfully Updated");
             con.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception error)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
         }

          for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
          {
              if (this.Controls[i] is TextBox)
              {
                  this.Controls[i].Text = "";
              }
          }
     }

     private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM members WHERE dID = '"+ txtdID.Text +"'";
         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM overview WHERE dID = '" + txtdID.Text + "'";
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

         MessageBox.Show("Record Scuessfully Deleted !");
         con.Close();

         for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
         {
             if (this.Controls[i] is TextBox)
             {
                 this.Controls[i].Text = "";
             }
         }
     }


     private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Application.Exit();
     }

 } }
```

Comment: Don't concatenate your sql string but use `Parameters` instead. You're open for SQL-Injection here: `SELECT * FROM Overview where dID =  '" + txtdID.Text`. Btw, why have you prepended all the `>` in the code? You can use the `Code`-Button to format the code in the editor. Have a look [**here**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Is this a homework question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try not to refrain from using direct SQL, in most cases - use a stored procedure. Where there isn't anything other than a simple select, use a view - then call your procedure from the front end.

Comment: @LukeHennerley that is a complex area, and there's no single answer. Using an SP/view can limit deployment flexibility and other things. Back a decade, there used to be *huge* advantages to SPs - but these days: they aren't really much different to *correctly parameterized* ad-hoc commands.

Comment: Do you have to hand code the SQL? Why not try and use LINQ to SQL instead. These look like a simple enough querys.

Comment: Narrow down your exact problems and ask a question per problem. If your problem is _"How do I get the totals per year per user"_, take a look at @AlexFilipovici's answer. If you want some UI advice, like _"Should I use my txtYear textbox for both input and output"_, then ask a question for that (and the answer is no). If you have a problem determining how to provide the user interface, show a screenshot and ask specific questions. This one is too broad and too localized at the same time, it will not help others.

Comment: @MarcGravell, as a rule of thumb I agree with the comment `they aren't really much different to correctly parameterized ad-hoc commands`. However, I have found that they still perform significantly better when querying large data sets using numerous joins (generally 10 or more). In fact, I saw a 87% performance increase on one occasion. So, it seems that they still have a purpose in that case, albeit probably an edge case for most developers, yes?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud it shouldn't have a difference there: they use the same pipeline. Obviously it is artificial to diagnose after the fact, but I would be tempted to suspect that was due to parameter sniffing, and simply making it recompile fixed the plan. That can be fixed for ad-hoc queries too.

Comment: @MarcGravell, I agree that the compilation of the plan was the issue, but am now interested in how I can get that to work the same for ad-hoc queries. And does the solution mean that the first query is slower (i.e. because it has to compile the plan) and subsequent requests are faster?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud yes and no, but **identically** yes and no for SPs vs ad-hoc. Both have a finite plan-cache. In both cases, the most appropriate "fix" would be to use appropriate `OPTIMIZE FOR` hints so it isn't disadvantaged hugely by skewed data on the first usage (i.e. so that the query that causes the plan to get cached doesn't ruin it for everyone). Note that this is very different to `WITH RECOMPILE` - it isn't a full recompile every run.

Comment: @MarcGravell, thank you, I will be researching the `OPTIMIZE FOR` directives!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud to be honest, `UNKNOWN` solves 90% of cases ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell, wow, I just read an article on the `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` and it cracks me up that if your application has any data at all (insert duh face here) that you would *almost always* need to use this option! However, it makes perfect sense what it does, it gets a chance to use statistical data to determine what the best optimization is. Question, does that also imply the more queries that hit the database the better the optimization (i.e. over time the HINT actually gets even better)?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I don't think so, but I'm afraid that is going a bit beyond my level. You would have to measure to get a good answer.

Comment: @MarcGravell, fair enough my friend, you've taken me to a new level today so thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a solution to the comments people have made regarding parameters and sql injection, i tend to use the code below when connecting to any database.

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING"))
{
    try
    {
        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM members where dID = @MyId";
            command.Connection = connection;

            // Set the SqlDbType to your corresponding type
            command.Parameters.Add("@MyId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtdID.Text;

            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                txtID.Text = reader["ID"].ToString();
                txtName.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
                txtAddress.Text = reader["Address"].ToString();
                txtMobile.Text = reader["Mobile"].ToString();
                txtEmail.Text = reader["Email"].ToString();
                txtdID.Text = reader["dID"].ToString();

            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much for your comments and criticism , believe me one learns a lot, but do forgive me for I may not live up to everyone’s standards . I value each and every comment. 
I have noticed that even though I tried to be more detailed and clear (may be because I am a newbie) that’s why people say too broad and too localized at the same time.

Comment: Well to sum it up I need to JUST for starters search for members paid amount for each Year!!! Don’t want sum of the amount don’t want annual sum, nothing like that.

Comment: I have John Doe in my database and for example his records for 10 years. Where for each year he has paid ( or should have paid 300 dollars full stop)

Comment: Now I can add new form and just want to search what he has paid for every year for let’s say for the past ten years.

Comment: I put in his dID and insert year 2002 result 300 paid! I put his dID again and insert 2005; result nothing he did not pay is yearly subscription in 2005 and I can continue so. 
At the end I can by this process that for the total of the ten years search I have done may be he has not paid for three years. 
That’s what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: So just change you SQL to "SELECT * FROM Overview where dID=@MyID and Year=@MyYear". Remember to apply the parameters as per my example above.

Comment: OK I applied you example in my search button, first part works as soon as I apply the second sql statement "SELECT * FROM Overview where dID=@MyID and Year=@MyYear" abd declare the second parameter "command.Parameters.Add("@MyYear", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtYear.Text;" I get error !failed to convert parameter value from string to Int32"

Comment: replace the parameter line to command.Parameters.Add("@MyYear", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtYear.Text)

Comment: Thank you Sir, works like a charm :o), so now I use the sam principal for Update and Insert with regards to SQL injection the Safe code snippet ?

Comment: I wonder can one add small condition here like if the record don't exit in the database, a pop up "member don't exist" instead of error which happens now.

Comment: yes you should use the exact same principle for updates, inserts and deletes. As for you second question, does a query return multiple records per year or is it only one record per user per year?

Comment: just one record ! by entering a single year it returns the amount for that year only so one query and one result.

Comment: in that case change while (reader.Read()){ // your current code } to if(reader.Read()){ // your current code } else { MessageBox.Show("user not found for that year")

Answer (score 0):

You need to group your `SELECT` on the `Amount` column. A simple answer to your question would be to modify your second select query like this:

```
sql = "SELECT Year, dID, SUM(Amount) as Amount FROM Overview where dID =  '" + txtdID.Text + "' AND Year = " + txtYear.Text + "GROUP BY amount";
```

Probably, you would like to use the `txtYear.Text` value for an SQL parameter, so:

```
txtYear.Text = sql;
```

and

```
txtYear.Text = txtYear.Text + " : " + sql;
```

don't make too much sense in your code.

Of course, this is not the correct way, as it is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I would recommend you to use [SQL Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), which are definitely safer regarding SQL Injection.

Another improvement to the code quality would be that you should use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statements to enclose the `SQLConnection`, `SQLCommand` and `SQLDataReader` objects initializations.